# the very first item picture can't show Magento

Tags: product-images

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.2.1

For the very first item of the first list on every page(if this page has a list, of course), the picture can't show. If there are more than one lists on that page, only the first has the problem.

So that means the very first item shown on every page has this problem.

I checked dev tools, it can be seen that image src has some problem. src="gethttp:......". And it should be src="http.....".

I thought it might be the problem with list.phtml code. But if that's the case, every first item in every list should have this problem.

Totally confused here. So which file should I look into?

Need help. Thanks

First, I am the author, can't you see the author is maggie as a guest and This is maggie3003 as a newly registered user?
I really want to post code here and get help, so please don't reject my edit again.
If I can leave code in comment, of course I'll do it. But I can't. I don't have enough reputation.

This is from list.phtml

```
<li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```

I finally found where went wrong.
I wanted to make magento be able to show gif pics. So I add something in code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php. In about line 490, I change the code to

```
public function getUrl()
{
    $baseDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
    $file = ('gif' == strtolower(pathinfo($this->_baseFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))) ? $this->_baseFile : $this->_newFile;
    $path = str_replace($baseDir . DS, "", $file);
    return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . str_replace(DS, '/', $path);
}
```

After I change it back, everything is fine now.

But now I can't use gif...

Comment: How is your list.phtml file?

Comment: Post the code of your list.phtml, It would be helpful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code from :

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>
```

To

```
<?php echo (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(135); ?>
```

Also `echo $_product->getImageUrl();` This method of the Product class should do the trick for you.